# Función ajax deja de funcionar al cambiar de página

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo la siguiente función con Ajax debajo de un archivo html y la primera vez que entro en la página ejecuta correctamente lo que hay dentro de **done**, sin embargo si voy a una página distinta y vuelvo he visto que al debuggear llega hasta el **done** pero luego sigue sin ejecutar **cb()**. La función **cb** se encarga de darle a una variable global los valores devueltos por el ajax y para utilizarlos después.

¿Alguna idea de lo que puede estar pasando?

```js
function consultaDisponibilidad() {

   vehiculo = $('#ficha-vehiculo').val();
                        
   $.ajax({
        data: {vehiculo: vehiculo},
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json"
                        
   }).done(function(value) {
             cb(value);
   });
}

consultaDisponibilidad();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que sucede es que tu funcion no recibe un `callback` deberia ser

```js
    var url = "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees";
    function consultaDisponibilidad(url,cb) {
       vehiculo = $('#ficha-vehiculo').val();
       vehiculo  ="";                  
       $.ajax({
            url:url,
            data: {vehiculo: vehiculo},
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json"
                            
       }).done(function(value) {
            cb(value);
       });
    }
    
    consultaDisponibilidad(url,function(data){
     console.log(data);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

puedes hacerlo asi usando un `return` en vez de un `callback`:

```js
    var url = "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees";

    function consultaDisponibilidad(url) {
        vehiculo = $('#ficha-vehiculo').val();
        vehiculo = "dataexample";
        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { vehiculo: vehiculo },
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json"
        })
    }

    consultaDisponibilidad(url)
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function(err){
     console.log("error!",err);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="resul"></div>
```